Using onEdit to trigger different functions on different sheets
I am working on a sheet that is recording inputs (scores) from multiple entry sheets. A data set on any given sheet has multiple entries, so I wanted to create a trigger to log the data when there is a full data set. I would use a button to submit/log the data to the main data log, but I intend to use a mobile version of Google Sheets to record data in the field, so I am using the onEdit() function using a checkbox to trigger the logging of the data and resetting of the entry form.
I have written a script that executes what I desire, but I am having trouble when I try to expand the script the 2nd - 4th entry sheets. Right now, as written, the entry works on the 'Entry1' sheet. However, when I try to execute the script from 'Entry2', it logs data from 'Entry1' and resets and rolls forward 'Entry1', as well as clearing the entries from 'Entry2', but not rolling the sheet forward to prepare for the subsequent entry.
What I am seeking is to have the script execute the appendScoreData function on the sheet in which the checkbox is checked (via onEdit). Right now, it seems to be performing some functions on entry sheets other than the one I am targeting.
MY CODE:
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function appendScoreData1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

//Collect Data1
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Entry1');
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange('Scores1');
var sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues().flat();

//Append Score Data1
const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA')
destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceVals)

//Clear Content
ss.getRange('GrossScores1').clearContent()

//Update Entry Form to Next Hole
ss.getRange('NextHole1').copyTo(ss.getRange('CurrentHole1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

//Active Cell Reset
ss.getRange('FirstScore1').activate();


};

function appendScoreData2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

//Collect Data2
var sourceSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Entry2');
var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet2.getRange('Scores2');
var sourceVals2 = sourceRange2.getValues().flat();

//Append Score Data2
const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA')
destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceVals2)

//Clear Content
ss.getRange('GrossScores2').clearContent()

//Update Entry Form to Next Hole
ss.getRange('NextHole2').copyTo(ss.getRange('CurrentHole2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

//Active Cell Reset
ss.getRange('FirstScore2').activate();


};

function onEdit(e) {
var range = e.range;
var spreadSheet = e.source;
var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();

if (range.sheetName = 'Entry1' && range.columnEnd == 3 && range.columnStart == 3 && range.rowEnd == 15 && range.rowStart == 15) {
  appendScoreData1();
  range.uncheck()
}

else if (range.sheetName = 'Entry2' && range.columnEnd == 3 && range.columnStart == 3 && range.rowEnd == 15 && range.rowStart == 15) {
  appendScoreData2();
  range.uncheck()
}    

}


Your using an assignment = for a comparison in the onEdit.  I would just pull all of the code into the onEdit and you can save a lot of code just by using the event object better.

Thanks Cooper. I should have said that I am a beginner using apps script..... I think you are referencing that I am using an = in my if statement? If I could just write the IF to reference different ranges that would result in onEdit performing different actions, then I would be good, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that...

You want to trigger a script if a checkbox in cell C15 on a given sheet is checked.
There are two problems:

you want to expand the number of sheets covered by the script.
the existing script is not executing on the appropriate sheet

The following answer addresses the problems and makes the script shorter and more efficient.

var sheets = ["Entry1","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"] - an array of sheet names includes the names of the sheets to be matched. Adding, deleting or amending a sheet to/from this list is as simple as updating the array.
var sheetMatch = sheets.indexOf(editedsheet) - indexOf is used to confirm whether the edited sheet is a sheet in the array.
if ( - an IF statement is used to test the sheet, column, row and checkbox status (TRUE)

if there are all valid, then a subroutine is called.
if even one is not valid, then no further action is taken.


function appendScoreData(sheetName) - only one subroutine is required; this carries the target sheet name as an argument.


function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  // get the relevant Event Objects
  var editedsheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedValue=e.value
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet = "+editedsheet+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited Columns = "+editedCol+", edited value = "+editedValue)

  // create an array of sheets to watch
  var sheets = ["Entry1","Entry2","Entry3","Entry4"]
  // use indexOF to test for edited sheet in the array of sheets
  var sheetMatch = sheets.indexOf(editedsheet)
  // Logger.log(sheetMatch) // DEBUG

  // test for the correct sheet, column, row and value
  if (sheetMatch !== -1 && editedCol == 3 && editedRow == 15&& editedValue == "TRUE") { // C15-checked
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: The sheet is = "+sheets[sheetMatch])
    appendScoreData(editedsheet)
    return
  }
  else{
    // not a valid match
    // Logger.log("No valid match") // DEBUG
}

}

function appendScoreData(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  Logger.log("do some stuff on sheet "+sheet.getName())
}

